# java windows file creation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i am checking the text file which is present in the mapped hard drive or not.

```
 File cfile = new File("R:\\Link Fixer Reports\\ServiceTest.txt");
```

but it shows that file is not present
when use `c:\\t.txt`
it shows the file

what is the problem and how can i rectify the problem?

Comment: And show us your error (if one occurs).

Comment: If your application is running as a windows service, the drive "R" is not mapped. Use the UNC-Path instead: \\server\share

Comment: Also, new File does not create a file in the file system. We have to call file.createNewFile(); for the file to be created.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the user that your code is running as can't see the mapped directory.

You've tagged this question as java-ee so I'd guess that this code is running within a web service or similar? What user is your application server running as? Verify that this user can access the location. As @Christian pointed out, a UNC-Path is a better way to go - just make sure that you can access the network location. Try [runas net use](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225035) to double-check.